# How can i reduce this lines in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have many number of following lines in jquery in the below format. I want to reduce the number of lines i am taking. Any suggestions pls !

```
//jquery
     $(function() { 
    $( "#draggable1" ).draggable({ revert: true, containment : '#removeme1', axis : 'x'});
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ revert: true, containment : '#removeme2', axis : 'x'});  
    $( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ revert: true, containment : '#removeme3', axis : 'x' });     
    $( "#draggable4" ).draggable({ revert: true, containment : '#removeme4', axis : 'x' });     
    $( "#draggable5" ).draggable({ revert: true, containment : '#removeme5', axis : 'x' }); 
    $( "#draggable6" ).draggable({ revert: true, containment : '#removeme6', axis : 'x' });     
    $( "#draggable7" ).draggable({ revert: true, containment : '#removeme7', axis : 'x' });

                       });
```

Comment: can you share the related html sample? is the `removeme7` element parent of `draggable7`?

Answer (score 3):

Just add a class, `draggable` and depending on the markup either set as containment the parent or store the containing element as attribute on the draggable element.

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({ revert: true, containment : 'parent', axis : 'x'});
```

in case the container is not the parent:

```
$( ".draggable" ).each(function(){
    $(this).draggable({ revert: true,
                     containment : $(this).data("container"),
                     axis : 'x'
                   });
});

// with the following HTML markup:

<div class="draggable" data-container="#removeme1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple for loop?

```
$(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        $("#draggable" + i).draggable({
            revert: true,
            containment: '#removeme' + i,
            axis: 'x'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a flexible solution to account for any number of draggables.

```
$(function () {
    $("div[id^='draggable']").each(function (index) {
        $(this).draggable({
            revert: true,
            containment: $(this).attr('id').val().replace('draggable', 'removeme'),
            axis: 'x'
        });
    });    
});
```

Comment: Two short comments: 1) `[id^='draggable']` has horrible performance and more importantly 2) who guarantees, that the elements are in the same order like their ID?

Comment: @Christoph - 1) define "horrible performance" (with proof/citation). Obviously common sense tells us that a "starts with" selector will be slower than others, but I have yet to experience "horrible" with this one in my own use 2) very good point, fixed.

Comment: Well, it's nothing that common sense wouldn't already tell you. But if you want a proof, how does [35 times slower sound?](http://jsperf.com/id-selector-vs-attribute-selector-extended)

Comment: Wouldn't comparing a class selector be a more accurate (since that is what you used)? Only ~12 times slower :) But point taken! http://jsperf.com/id-selector-vs-attribute-selector-extended/2

Comment: That was just a general statement, that those attribute selectors should be used with care. I wasn't directly comparing it to any other selector. But of course you are right, an ID selector is fastest, and attribute selectors are slowest with classes somewhere in between. Anyhow, with your updated answer working properly +1. Cheers;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var someArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    $.each(someArr, function (i, val) {
        $("#draggable" + val).draggable({
            revert: true,
            containment: '#removeme' + val,
            axis: 'x'
        });
    });

});
```